# Getting value from a nested xml with attributes using minidom and etree

Tags: python, lxml, minidom

I have the following xml data:

```
<response>
   <status>ok</status>
   <message>Done</message>
   <local-data>
      <name>
         <attribute key="first">John</attribute>
         <attribute key="middle">Maverick</attribute>
         <attribute key="last">Doe</attribute>
      <name>
   </local-data>
</response>
```

How would one extract the value of "first" or "middle" from the xml using minidom and any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

This code should help

```
dom1 = parseString(xml_text)
elements = dom1.getElementsByTagName("attribute")
for element in elements:
    if element.getAttribute('key') == "first":
        print(element.firstChild.nodeValue)
```